# Play midi with Core Midi on device

Tags: ios, coremidi

I 've been using CoreMidi to connect to USB devices and/or WiFi hosts. It works fine and sends my midi events.

I want to send them to the device itself to be played. Like the MusicPlayer, but I don't want to send midi files, just my own midi events.

What should I do? I tried connecting to the first destination available (MIDIGetNumberOfDestinations) but it didn't work.

Comment: This answer may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952151/can-anyone-show-me-how-to-use-coremidi-on-ios/14110218#14110218

Answer (score 0):

A corrected answer now that I understand better the question.

A sample of one of my projects.

```
    // Setup MIDI input port
    MIDIClientRef client = NULL;
    MIDIPortRef inport = NULL;
    CheckError (MIDIClientCreate(CFSTR("MyApplication"), 
                                 NULL, 
                                 NULL, 
                                 &client),
                "Couldn't create MIDI client");
    CheckError (MIDIInputPortCreate(client,
                                     CFSTR("MyApplication Input port"), 
                                     &inport),
                "Couldn't create input port");

    [self setInputPort:inport];
    [self setMidiClient:client];
    [self setDestinationEndpoint:[[self midiSession] destinationEndpoint]];
```

Comment: I 've already done that, but it just says what I 've already done I think.

Comment: Just enhanced my answer, hope it helps

Comment: The problem is, to which CoreMIDI endpoint to send the data in order to be played from the device itself, with a soundfont also.